# Using query builder for adding fulltext index in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, full-text-indexing, laravel-query-builder

This is the query for adding fulltext index in MySQL:

```
ALTER TABLE `TableName`
ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `IndexName` (`ColumnName`);
```

But How can I use Laravel query builder to add fulltext index?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it: `DB::statement`

`DB::statement('ALTER TABLE TableName ADD FULLTEXT INDEX IndexName (ColumnName)');`

Answer (score 4):

**Update**: As of Laravel >= 8.74.0 the fulltext indexes are supported natively, see the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#available-index-types

On Laravel >= 6.15.0 you can extend `Illuminate\Database\Schema\Grammars\MySqlGrammar` and `Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint` classes like this (e.g. on `boot()` method of your `AppServiceProvider`):

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Grammars\MySqlGrammar;
use Illuminate\Support\Fluent;

Blueprint::macro('fulltext', function ($columns, $name = null, $algorithm = null)
{
    return $this->indexCommand('fulltext', $columns, $name, $algorithm);
});

Blueprint::macro('dropFulltext', function ($index)
{
    return $this->dropIndexCommand('dropIndex', 'fulltext', $index);
});

MySqlGrammar::macro('compileFulltext', function (Blueprint $blueprint, Fluent $command)
{
    return $this->compileKey($blueprint, $command, 'fulltext');
});
```

And use it on your migrations like this:

```php
Schema::table('flights', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->fulltext(['name', 'airline']);
});

//reverse the migration
Schema::table('flights', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dropFulltext(['name', 'airline']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For multiple `Columns/Fields`

```
DB::statement('ALTER TABLE Database.TableName ADD FULLTEXT fulltext_index (Col_1, col_2, col_3)');
```